# Large number of columns in Outlook 2013 and 2016

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have the following HTML code for email :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>

<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
<th>AAAAA</th>
<th>BBBBB</th>
<th>CCCCC</th>
<th>DDDDD</th>
<th>EEEEE</th>
<th>FFFFF</th>
<th>GGGGG</th>
<th>HHHHH</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<style>
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

In Outlook 2016, the texts are truncated and in outlook 2013 they are broken in to several lines. 
Outlook 2016: 
[image]
Outlook 2013: 
[image]
Is there any way to resolve the issue ? I want to see the whole text in one line, and headers next to each other. I tried `table-layout`, `width:auto` and many other things, but nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook supports `white-space:nowrap;`, so if you inline that into each `<th>` that should force each cell to not wrap:

```
<th style="white-space: nowrap;>AAAAA</th>
<th style="white-space: nowrap;>BBBBB</th>
<th style="white-space: nowrap;>CCCCC</th>

....

<th style="white-space: nowrap;>FFFFF</th>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Still it's the same.